# Formulate Newtons method for system of equations.

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

**Some background theory:** By Taylor's theorem we know that an approximation of $f(x)$ with two terms around an approximation $x_k\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is given by $f(x)\approx f(x_k)+J(x_k)(x-x_k),$ where $J$ is the jacobian. So a linear model of our problem $f(x)=0$ becomes

$$f(x_k)+J(x_k)(x-x_k)=0. \tag{1}$$

The solution to the system (1), is taken as our new approximation $x_{k+1}.$ If we let $s_k=x_{k+1}-x_k,$ one iteration with Newtons method can be written as

$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    J(x_k)s_k & = & -f(x_k) \\
    x_{k+1} & = & x_k+s_k \\
  \end{array}
\right. \tag{2}$$

> **Problem:** Formulate Newtons method for the system
>
> $$\left\{   \begin{array}{rcr}
>      x_1^2+x_2^2 & = & 1 \\
>     x_1^2-x_2 & = & 0 \\   \end{array} \right.$$

First of all, I don't see how we can have the jacobian $J(x_k)$ of one variable. We are still working with a single variable function $f$ as I understand but somehow we can start using Jacobians. I feel I need a better explanation of the background theory.

Second, the anser in the book is

$$\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}^{(k+1)}=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}^{(k)}+\begin{pmatrix} d_1 \\ d_2\end{pmatrix}^{(k)}.$$

I see that this is related to the second row in (2) but what is the last matrix in terms of $d_1, \ d_2?$

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to reformulate Newton's method assuming everything is now a vector -- you have a vector of coordinates, $\vec{x}$, a vector of functions, $\vec{f}$, and a matrix of derivatives, $J$.

You have a vector of functions receiving a vector of $x$s.  Written as vectors, 
$$  \vec{f}(\vec{x}) = \dots  \text{.}  $$
Written with explicit components, 
$$  \begin{pmatrix} f_1 \\ f_2 \end{pmatrix}\left( \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} \right) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1^2 + x_2^2 \\ x_1 - x_2 \end{pmatrix}  \text{.}  $$

Then the Jacobian is 
$$  J(\vec{x}) = \left. \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} \\ \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2} \end{pmatrix} \right|_{\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} = \vec{x}}  $$ 
where, for example, $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} = 2x_1$.